# Sorting "day" "week" "month" and "year"

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of objects from an API

```
[
{path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_1', time: 'day'}
1: {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_2', time: 'week'}
2: {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_1', time: 'year'}
3: {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_1', time: 'week'}
4: {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_1', time: 'month'}
5: {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_2', time: 'day'}
6: {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_2', time: 'month'}
7: {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_2', time: 'year'}
]
```

I want to sort them based on time but when I do,
it goes like

```
day
month
week
year
```

Is there any way to make it like:

```
day
week
month
year
```

I am using functional component in javascript.

Comment: How are you currently performing the sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sorting function, you are comparing with the string that's why you are getting a sorted list with alphabetic order. If you want a custom order you can create a map to follow the order.

```js
const data = [
  {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_1', time: 'day'},
  {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_2', time: 'week'},
  {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_1', time: 'year'},
  {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_1', time: 'week'},
  {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_1', time: 'month'},
  {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_2', time: 'day'},
  {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_2', time: 'month'},
  {path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_2', time: 'year'},
];

const timeMap = {
  day: 0,
  week: 1,
  month: 2,
  year: 3,
}

data.sort((a, b) => {
  return timeMap[a.time] - timeMap[b.time];
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: A more "stable" sort can be achieved by using `data.sort((a, b) => {
  return timeMap[a.time]-timeMap[b.time];
});`. Your current callback function will not return `0` for equal elements.

Answer (score 2):

use the sort method like this
mdn : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```js
let arr = 
[
{path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_1', time: 'day'},
{path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_2', time: 'week'},
{path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_1', time: 'year'},
{path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_1', time: 'week'},
{path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_1', time: 'month'},
{path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_2', time: 'day'},
{path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_2', time: 'month'},
{path: 'image', location: 'LOCATION_2', time: 'year'}
];
let sortBy = ["day", "week", "month", "year"]
console.log(arr.sort((a,b) => sortBy.indexOf(a.time) - sortBy.indexOf(b.time)))
```